# Code for Python Package OS for opening an application in Windows 10

Tags: python

I am making an application which opens an app by user command. 
It is showing "The system cannot find the file -a."

What is the correct command for this piece of code.

```
if "launch" or "open" in text:
    app = text.split(" ", 1)[-1]
    self.respond("Opening " + app)
    os.system("start -a " + app + ".app")
```

Comment: Why don’t you use the subprocess module? The os module is very low-level and assumes familiarity with the Operating System.

Comment: If I type your command at a Windows console prompt: `C:\Users\xxxx>start -a notepad.app` I get exactly the error you report. Before issuing an OS command to do something, it's important to be sure that the command you are issuing actually works. If it doesn't, calling `os.system` won't fix anything. And don't use `os.system`. It's been deprecated for years.